# Minimal unsatisfiable core algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sat

I'm looking for a polynomial algorithm to find a [minimal unsatisfiable core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsatisfiable_core) of a given CNF formula. In other words, an algorithm that if it inputs a Boolean unsatisfiable CNF, it outputs a subset of the clauses of the given CNF such that they are unsatisfiable and become satisfiable when we remove a clause from the subset. If the give CNF is satisfiable, the algorithm returns a satisfiable subset of the clauses of the given CNF. The algorithm complexity must be polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Given that deciding if a CNF is satisfiable or unsatisfiable is NP-complete (unless P=NP) you will not find a polynomial algorithm for this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Comment: The algorithm that I'm looking for doesn't decide if the given CNF **F** is satisfiable or unsatisfiable, infact it outputs a subset **S** of the given clauses such that if **F** is satisfiable **S** is satisfiable; if **F** is unsatisfiable **S** is minimal unsatisfiable. Therefore the output of the algorithm is a CNF but we don't know if it satisfiable or not.